# unable to call (or attach a function to)onclick method on an object returned by getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

1)

```
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello Worl";);
```

2)

```
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function()
{document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "HelloWorld!";}
```

Please help. I think both are different ways to do the same thing. But the second method is not working.

Comment: there is a syntax error with the definition of the first handler and by the way the second works for me.

Comment: Assuming the error Blauharley mentions is just a typo, they do *similar* things, yes. And both should work, provided the element exists when you run that code.

Comment: The second code worked fine.The problem was the ordering of the tags.When i placed the script to bottom of my HTML body it works fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add the onclick in the Html:

```
<button value="Some Text" onclick="click()" id="demo"></button>
<script>
function click(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World";
}
</script>
```

Another Method:

```
onload = demo;
function demo() {
     var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
     demo.onclick = click;
}
function click(){
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Some text";
}
```

I hope this was helpful. If not leave a comment.

Comment: Actually my problem was with the placing of the script tag.So when i placed it after the "demo" element it worked fine.And also i am little confused with your second method.What is that sb object ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your closing bracket

```
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello Worl";
);
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello Worl";
});
```

The second method should work fine, are you sure you have a proper element on the page with this id?

Here's a fiddle with this example

https://jsfiddle.net/wvty8rpc/1/

Comment: thanks.The first method was working fine with me..i made mistake while typing the same here.My problem is with second method.I cant assign onclick that function on its right side.I know there are other methods to do the same.But i just want to know why the second method is not working.

Comment: Check out the jsfiddle I linked. I used the second method in the link, and it works as intended. If you've got everything typed out correctly- then there might be another culprit causing it to fail. You would need to link more of your source in order to diagnose that. The HTML would be a good starting point.

Comment: Hi,
your code works fine ..the problem was mine :) 
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="demo" >demo</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "HelloWorld!";
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: when i placed the script tag after the element with "demo" id it worked

Comment: That'll do it, glad you got it!